# ajax function throwing HTTP 200 immediately followed by HTTP 500 error

Tags: ajax, django, internal-server-error

Why do I get a HTTP 200 followed immediately by a HTTP 500? I have the impression the Ajax function is called twice in a row. The objects that I expect to be created are actually created though...

my ajax function is called on a form submit:

```
$(document).on('submit','#like_form_reading_list{{ article.pk }}', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url "userprofile:like" %}',
    data: {
        journal: '{{ journal.pk }}',
        section: '{{ section.pk }}',
        article: '{{ article.pk }}',
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
    success: function showAlertLike() {
        $("#success_like").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
    },
    error: function showAlertPin() {
        $("#error_like").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
    }
});
});
```

In my view:

```
class LikeView(generic.FormView):
"""
A view that creates a LikedArticles object when a user clicks on the like badge under each article displayed.
"""

def post(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        journal_pk = request.POST.get('journal')
        section_pk = request.POST.get('section')
        article_pk = request.POST.get('article')

        journal = Journal.objects.get(pk=journal_pk)
        section = Section.objects.get(pk=section_pk)
        article = Article.objects.get(pk=article_pk)

        print('IN LIKE VIEW  ', user, journal_pk, section_pk, article_pk)

        LikedArticles.objects.create(
            user=user,
            journal=journal,
            section=section,
            article=article
        )

    return HttpResponse('')
```

In my terminal:

Internal Server Error: /like/

Traceback (most recent call last):

[SOME ERROR MESSAGE]

"/Users/benoitkoenig/Desktop/projet_web/harrispierce_django/hpdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 966, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

('IN LIKE VIEW  ',  at 0x107eb5c80>>, u'1', u'2', u'2390')

[31/Oct/2017 18:59:58] "POST /like/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0

[31/Oct/2017 18:59:59] "POST /like/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18107

Comment: Not related to your question, so I don't post it as an answer but as a suggestion: you can create the `LikedArticles` object like this:

`LikedArticles.objects.create(user=user, journal_id=journal_pk,  section_id=section_pk, article_id=articcle_pk)`

You don't have to retrieve those objects from db first.

Comment: oh cool, I'll try that